# Where are all the terminal commands stored and how to view them?

Tags: command-line

I forgot the terminal command for viewing the disk space. So I began with the resources for terminal commands like pdf and webpages.
Aren't those terminal commands stored somewhere in the file syster?
In that case where are they stored and how can I see the terminal commands? 
PS: It will be like a single command which lists and displays all the rest of command that are stored in the system.

Comment: See also [Linux command to list all available commands and aliases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/949006)

Comment: Note that there are several kinds of terminal commands. There are "shell built-ins", which the shell (usually *bash*) executes directly. Then there are aliases (listed and set with command `alias`) and shell functions (similar to aliases) which are a bit like "user-defined built-ins". Then there are the programs in file system and found in current `PATH`, which are checked only after the previous ones don't apply. Then there are the programs in file system but not in `PATH`, which need to be launched with path (most common case `./program`). There's no single command to list them all.

Comment: ...and then you could classify different kinds of programs found in file system differently. Some are clearly "shell commands" (like `df` from your question), some are clearly not (like `firefox`), and some depend on what exactly you mean by "shell command" (like `vim` or `nano`). There's no good automatic way to do this classification, really.

Comment: If you're ever in the situation that you remember what a command started with, but not the full name, then you can often just type "TAB TAB" to view the possible completions of that command. For example, a bunch of Apache (web server) commands start with "a2", so I just type "a2 TAB TAB" and bash will show me `a2disconf  a2dismod   a2dissite  a2enconf   a2enmod    a2ensite   a2p        a2query`

Answer (score 22):

You could try using the `apropos` command to find a command knowing a basic idea of the command. For e.g, if you need to find a command for handling `disk` functions try: `apropos disk`. Advantage of using `apropos` is that it gives a short description of the command.

**e.g:**

```
$ apropos disk
arm_sync_file_range (2) - sync a file segment with disk
baobab (1)           - A graphical tool to analyze disk usage
cfdisk (8)           - display or manipulate disk partition table
cgdisk (8)           - Curses-based GUID partition table (GPT) manipulator
df (1)               - report file system disk space usage
dvd+rw-booktype (1)  - format DVD+-RW/-RAM disk with a logical format
dvd+rw-format (1)    - format DVD+-RW/-RAM disk
dvd+rw-mediainfo (1) - display information about dvd drive and disk
fdformat (8)         - low-level format a floppy disk
fdisk (8)            - manipulate disk partition table
gdisk (8)            - Interactive GUID partition table (GPT) manipulator
git-count-objects (1) - Count unpacked number of objects and their disk consumption
git-credential-store (1) - Helper to store credentials on disk
gnome-disk-image-mounter (1) - Attach and mount disk images
gnome-disks (1)      - the GNOME Disks application
grub-mkstandalone (1) - make a memdisk-based GRUB image
grub-render-label (1) - generate a .disk_label for Apple Macs.
hd (4)               - MFM/IDE hard disk devices
initrd (4)           - boot loader initialized RAM disk
mbadblocks (1)       - tests a floppy disk, and marks the bad blocks in the FAT
mcat (1)             - dump raw disk image
mcheck (1)           - verify all files on an MS-DOS formatted disk
memdiskfind (1)      - utility to search for a MEMDISK instance
mformat (1)          - add an MSDOS filesystem to a low-level formatted floppy disk
mkdiskimage (1)      - Create a blank MS-DOS formatted hard disk image
mmount (1)           - mount an MSDOS disk
mpartition (1)       - partition an MSDOS hard disk
mtools (1)           - utilities to access DOS disks in Unix.
mxtar (1)            - Wrapper for using GNU tar directly from a floppy disk
mzip (1)             - change protection mode and eject disk on Zip/Jaz drive
netscsid (1)         - write data to optical disk media
partx (8)            - tell the Linux kernel about the presence and numbering of on-disk partitions
quotactl (2)         - manipulate disk quotas
ram (4)              - ram disk device
sd (4)               - driver for SCSI disk drives
sfdisk (8)           - partition table manipulator for Linux
sgdisk (8)           - Command-line GUID partition table (GPT) manipulator for Linux and Unix
sync (2)             - commit buffer cache to disk
sync (8)             - synchronize data on disk with memory
sync_file_range (2)  - sync a file segment with disk
sync_file_range2 (2) - sync a file segment with disk
syncfs (2)           - commit buffer cache to disk
udisks (8)           - Disk Manager
udisksctl (1)        - The udisks command line tool
udisksd (8)          - The udisks system daemon
usb-creator-gtk (8)  - Ubuntu startup disk creation tool for Gtk+
wodim (1)            - write data to optical disk media
```

As for the location of the system commands, most command are stored in the following directories:

```
/bin/
/usr/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

You can use the `ls` command to list the specific commands stored in each of these directories.

For further information:

- [Manpage for `apropos`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apropos.1)

**Update:**

You can use `echo $PATH`, to find all the paths presently specified for executable:

e.g:

```
$ echo $PATH

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Then you can use `ls` on each of the individual folders(each folder is separated by a `:` ) to find the executable commands present in that path.

> PATH is an environment variable on Unix-like operating systems, DOS,
>   OS/2, and Microsoft Windows, specifying a set of directories where
>   executable programs are located. In general, each executing process or
>   user session has its own PATH setting.

**Courtesy:** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29

The number in the brackets of the `apropos` output refers to the `man` section number. The `man` pages have been categorized into various sections, namely:

1. **Commands (Programs)**

   Those commands that can be executed by the user from within a shell.
2. **System calls**

   Those functions which must be performed by the kernel.
3. **Library calls**

   Most of the libc functions.
4. **Special files (devices)**

   Files found in /dev.
5. **File formats and conventions**

   The format for /etc/passwd and other human-readable files.
6. **Games**
7. **Overview, conventions, and miscellaneous**

   Overviews  of  various  topics,  conventions  and  protocols, character set standards, and miscellaneous other things.
8. **System management commands**

   Commands like mount(8), many of which only root can execute. System administration commands (usually only for root)
9. **Kernel routines [Non standard]**

**Courtesy:** http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man7/man-pages.7.html

Comment: $echo $PATH that will tell your where all your commands are. you can take the output of the $PATH varaiable and do somethign like: $ls /bin /usr/local /usr/bin and get lists of all the things in your path.

Comment: What is the number in brackets referring to?

Comment: Those are the sections of the manual. Typically, the on-line manual has different sections for e.g. user commands, system administrator commands, library functions, file formats, et al. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/what-do-the-numbers-in-a-man-page-mean

Comment: @j0h, Thanks for the information, I have added it to the answer. I didn't think of using the PATH variable, that was pretty good thinking. :)

Comment: @Trengot, Those are `man` section numbers, I have added detailed information to the answer.

Comment: heres a command to browse the available commands in the $PATH: y="$(echo $PATH | sed 's/:/ /g')" && ls $y | less

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `man -k <keyword>` to search for any command based on the particular keyword. `apropos` mentioned in other answer actually uses the database generated by `mandb`. So, both of the following will produce same output:

```
man -k disk
apropos disk
```

Both of the above provides regular expressions based pattern search by default.

See the manpages of [`man`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/man.1.html) and [`apropos`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man1/apropos.1.html) for details.